# Powershell command to get all files from multiple folders based on filter

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, azure-powershell

I am trying to build a powershell command to extract all files from multiple folder and combine into a single file.

> Basefolder > 
> Release1 > sp01.sql
> > sp02.sql 
> Release2 > sp03.sql
> > sp04.sql
> > sp05.sql

I need to combine the scripts into single sql file.

The script I tried:

```
Get-ChildItem $(Pipeline.Workspace)/BaseFolder -Filter "Release*" -include "*.sql" -rec | 
    ForEach-Object {gc $_; "GO"} | 
    Out-File $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/combined-script.sql
```

It returns an empty file. Can you help with this?

Comment: Have you tried... anything? :-)

Comment: Did you forget to ask your question?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes, I have added the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Get-ChildItem` provider cmdlet is perfectly capable of enumerating and filtering files from multiple directories at once:

```
$sqlScripts = Get-ChildItem -Path .\path\to\Release1,.\path\to\Release2 -File -Filter *.sql
```

You can also chain multiple `Get-ChildItem` invocations to have the first one feed the base directories to the second:

```
$sqlScripts = Get-ChildItem -Path .\base\Release* -Directory |Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.sql
```

Now you just need to read the contents of all the files and write them to a new one:

```
$sqlScripts |ForEach-Object { $_ |Get-Content; "GO" } |Set-Content .\path\to\concatenated.sql
```

Comment: What if I had to add "GO" at end of each file?

Comment: Is there a way to add text say "IF EXISTS()" before each file content?

Comment: @user3441903 have you tried adding `"IF EXISTS()";` at the start of the ForEach-Object block?

Comment: @user3441903 is there are problem with the answer?